# Need to install JAI Image I/O package. https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio/

Tags: java, eclipse, tiff, jai

I have a java program where I added **JAI Image I/O** to support **TIFF** image format.

**A) What is working fine**

This program runs perfectly in the **Eclipse environment** and this code prints class name (I suppose it is the one responsible for ) and **returns true** i.e. TIFF image writer is registered:

```
    System.out.println(TIFFImageWriterSpi.class);
    ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
    Iterator<ImageWriter> it = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff");
    System.out.println(it.hasNext());
```

**A) My Issue**

I **packed the project using gradle**. The resulting JAR contains the classes responsible for TIFF processing:

```
     com\github\jaiimageio\impl\plugins\tiff\TIFFImageWriter.class 
     com\github\jaiimageio\impl\plugins\tiff\TIFFImageWriterSpi.class
```

Unfortunately it when executed the **same code**, the *it.hasNext()* return false, i.e. it failed to  **register TIFF writers** using ImageIO.scanForPlugins();*
and becasue of this also this exception was thrown:

```
Need to install JAI Image I/O package. https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio/
```

although *JAI Image I/O* is already in class path (otherwise the Eclipse run would fail)

Comment: Just wondering though, why would you choose TIFF over any other image format?

Comment: `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` scans for plugins on the class path using `ServiceLoader`and the JAR file [Service Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service_Provider) mechanism. It's not enough to just have the compiled classes. Do you also have the appropriate service provider configuration files in your JAR (ie. `/META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi`)? If you do, does it contain a line saying `com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriterSpi`?

Answer (score 0):

Using this code:

```
IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance().registerServiceProvider(
             new TIFFImageWriterSpi(), ImageWriterSpi.class);
```

it is possible to manually register any ImageWriterSpi  or ImageReaderSpi even when ImageIO.scanForPlugins(); fails.